# Strange behavior with sockets when restarting node - any ideas?

Tags: node.js, sockets

I've written a simple node.js/socket.io/express/redis server. I'm trying to get the clients to reinitialize when I kill and restart the server.

My client-side code looks like this:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://' + location.hostname); 
socket.on('connect', function (data) {socket.emit('join room', 'lobby' );});
```

My server-side code looks like this:

```
var SessionSockets = require('session.socket.io')
  , sessionSockets = new SessionSockets(io, sessionStore, cookieParser);

sessionSockets.on('connection', function (err, socket, session) {
    clientConnect(err, socket, session)
});

function clientConnect(err, socket, session){
  socket.on('join room', function (room) {
    if (room == 'lobby')
      lobby.connect(err,socket,session);
  });
}
```

EDIT:
For some reason, when I kill the server (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>), and restart it, the connection handshake gets logged, and the server always emits a 'connect' but when the client follows suit and emits a 'join room' upon receiving the connect the server doesn't receive it (I'm doing a console.log on receiving a join room.)

However, if I put a client-side alert before emitting the 'join room' (forcing a delay essentially) then the code always works. Is it possible that the server hasn't fully initialized when the client sends the 'join room' event?

Comment: What's particularly strange is that if I added an alert('here'); to the client-side code before emitting the 'join room' the alert always triggers and the code always works, but when I remove the alert then it doesn't always work. Does that imply it's somehow a timing issue? That the emit somehow fires too soon without the alert?

Comment: Anyone have any good ideas?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of things that might go wrong here,but first you can try listening to client event about reconnecting..

client side code, to listen when reconnecting

```
socket.on('reconnecting',function(){ 
 socket.emit('join room','lobby');
});
```

*( a theory never actually encounter this)*

Then there might be misbehavior when the app stops, and you are using Redis to store sessions, you restart app, and sessions are still available.. to workaround on such an issue

```
process.on("SIGINT",function(){
 // clean up
});
```

or when app starts make sure it cleans up session storage, and then continues..

Comment: I updated my question. It turns out that the server does always emit the 'connect' event, however, when the client emits the 'join room' the server doesn't always acknowledge it. I'm wondering if the server hasn't had a chance to initialize or something?